# Getting to grips with the iCommand Design pattern

Tags: c#, wpf

Trying to learn WPF and I have read/tested with a tutorial.

This is my scenario:

A wpf C# application.
My main window has a UserControl on it.
This UserControl has 4 buttons on it.
My intent is to bind each command(click) event to each button.
But instead of binding each button to its own class I want to bind each command event of these 4 buttons to 1 class.
So.. I wanted to pass a parameter to the CanExecute and Execute methods and I was/am trying to pass an enum to these methods.
so.. what i have got so far is this:

```
public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
{
    add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
    remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
}

public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
{
    var commandChosen= parameter as TopMenuCommands;
    return true;
}

public void Execute(object parameter)
{
    var buttonChosen = parameter as MenuCommandObject;
    evMenuChange(buttonChosen);
}

public enum enTopMenuCommands
{
    Button1 = 0,
    Button1 = 1,
    Button1 = 2,
    Button1 = 3
}
```

But how can I tie this to my main window?

I admit I maybe doing this all completely wrong but I am still learning.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My `ICommand` implementation takes an `Action<object>` in the constructor. The `Execute` method just invoked the `Action`.

That way the logic for each command is passed in from where it is created.

**ICommand Implementation:**

```
public class SimpleCommand : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        private Action<object> _execute;
        private Func<bool> _canExecute;

        public SimpleCommand(Action<object> execute) : this(execute, null) { }

        public SimpleCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<bool> canExecute)
        {
            _execute = execute;
            _canExecute = canExecute;
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object param)
        {
            if (_canExecute != null)
            {
                return _canExecute.Invoke();
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        public void Execute(object param)
        {
            _execute.Invoke(param);
        }

        protected void OnCanExecuteChanged()
        {
            CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this,EventArgs.Empty);
        }

        #region Common Commands
        private static SimpleCommand _notImplementedCommand;
        public static ICommand NotImplementedCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_notImplementedCommand == null)
                {
                    _notImplementedCommand = new SimpleCommand(o => { throw new NotImplementedException(); });
                }
                return _notImplementedCommand;
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

**Usage Example:**

```
using System;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Input;
using SqlMetaQuery.Model;
using SqlMetaQuery.ViewModels.ScriptList;
using SqlMetaQuery.Windows.EditQuery;
using WpfLib;

namespace SqlMetaQuery.Windows.Main
{
    class MainWindowVm : WpfLib.ViewModel
    {
        public MainWindowVm()
        {
            if (!IsInDesignMode)
            {
                using (Context db = new Context())
                {
                    ScriptTree = new ScriptTreeVm(db.Tags
                        .Include(t => t.Scripts)
                        .OrderBy(t => t.Name));

                    CurrentUser = db.Users.Where(u => u.UserName == "Admin").AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();
                    MiscTag = db.Tags.Where(t => t.Name == "Misc").AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault();

                }
            }
        }

        public ScriptTreeVm ScriptTree { get; }

        public Model.User CurrentUser { get; }

        private Model.Tag MiscTag { get; }

        private void SaveScript(Model.Script script)
        {
            using (var context = new Model.Context())
            {
                context.Scripts.Add(script);
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }

        #region Commands

        private ICommand _exitCommand;
        public ICommand ExitCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_exitCommand == null)
                {
                    _exitCommand = new SimpleCommand((arg) => WindowManager.CloseAll());
                }
                return _exitCommand;
            }
        }

        private ICommand _newScriptCommand;
        public ICommand NewScriptCommand
        {
            get
            {
                if (_newScriptCommand == null)
                {
                    _newScriptCommand = new SimpleCommand((arg) =>
                    {
                        var script = new Model.Script()
                        {
                            Title = "New Script",
                            Description = "A new script.",
                            Body = ""
                        };
                        script.Tags.Add(MiscTag);
                        var vm = new EditQueryWindowVm(script);
                        var result = WindowManager.DisplayDialogFor(vm);

                        // if (result.HasValue && result.Value)
                        //{
                        script.VersionCode = Guid.NewGuid();
                        script.CreatedBy = CurrentUser;
                        script.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
                        SaveScript(script);
                        //}
                    });
                }
                return _newScriptCommand;
            }
        }


        #endregion
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="SqlMetaQuery.Windows.Main.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:SqlMetaQuery.Controls"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SqlMetaQuery.Windows.Main"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="800"
        Height="600"
        d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=local:MainWindowVm}"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <DockPanel>
        <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <MenuItem Header="File">
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=NewScriptCommand}" Header="New Script..." />
                <Separator />
                <MenuItem Command="{Binding Path=ExitCommand}" Header="Exit" />
            </MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        <Grid Margin="8">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="250" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <controls:ScriptTree Grid.Row="0"
                                 Grid.Column="0"
                                 DataContext="{Binding Path=ScriptTree}" />
            <GridSplitter Grid.Row="0"
                          Grid.Column="1"
                          Width="8"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" />
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="8" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Border Grid.Row="0" Style="{StaticResource BorderStandard}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ScriptTree.CurrentScript.Title}" />
                </Border>
                <Border Grid.Row="3" Style="{StaticResource BorderStandard}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ScriptTree.CurrentScript.Body}" />
                </Border>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

Comment: Hi, i know I must appear pretty dim here but is it possible for you to give me an example in the context of what I am trying to do? What is best practice? thanks

Comment: Updated with examples of implementation and usage.

Comment: wow! thanks. Let me digest this and get back to you. Good of you to do this

Comment: I just realized that the example of usage I gave you may be slightly confusing because it is actually an ICommand that deals with "commands" in my application.  Let me find you one where you don't have to deal with trying to parse that...

Comment: :) I was just about to send a comment saying that. You obviously know your stuff and makes me feel very insignificant. I doubt if you are ever out of work!

Comment: Updated with a better example of usage.

Comment: thanks - I am going to need some time to comprehend this

Comment: Hi, i am confused how to implement this when I compare it to MVVM tutorial I am following. I am going to edit my question to include this example I am working from if I may

Comment: I keep this and a lot of other common WPF stuff I use all the time in a library that I reference in all my projects.  You can see the source code at https://bitbucket.org/BradleyUffner/wpflib/, feel free to use it in anything you like.

Comment: How do I bind the button to all this?

Comment: That was an accident.  I've updated my answer to show the full window's view model, plus the XAML that references it.

Comment: OK, thanks for the previous link and for your update. I may need a few hours but i will get back - ta